# Adding a # symbol and redirecting to a url using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am attempting to rewrite the URL on my website using the .htaccess but have had no luck so far. I want to add a hash to the URL and redirect.

I want to get the last file in the URL and redirect it to the same URL but append a # symbol before the last file. The reason I want to do this is for my website, all the content is loaded dynamically without refreshing the page.

For example,
[www.example.com/foo](http://www.example.com/foo) would become [www.example.com/#foo](http://www.example.com/#foo)

or
[www.example.com/form/bar.php](http://www.example.com/form/bar.php) would become [www.example.com/form/#bar.php](http://www.example.com/form/#bar.php)

I don't mind if I need one entry for each page, I have tried many variations but nothing has worked so far.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)foo(.*)$ $1#foo$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /$1#$2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^foo/?$ /#$0 [L,NE,R=301,NC]`

Comment: This kind of works, but it replaced everything with the #foo. So my local instance 
http://localhost/mywebsite/foo becomes http://localhost/#foo

Comment: Ok I will edit to make it clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have it this way in your .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)([^/]+/?)$
RewriteRule ^ %1#%2 [L,NE,R=301]
```

A note about `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)([^/]+/?)$`:

We are using 2 capture groups in regex here:

- `(.*/)`: Match longest match before last `/` being represented as `%1` later
- `([^/]+/?)`: Match last component of URI being represented as `%2` later

In target we use `%1#%2` to place a `#` between 2 back references.

Comment: Can you briefly explain how this works, please?

Comment: Yes added it in question

Answer (score 1):

something like this...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/* /#$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there's quiet a few things wrong here, such as... the _pattern_ `^/*` will never match, the `$1` backreference is always empty, the `#` will be URL-encoded in the response (if this was a "redirect"), this is not a redirect (it needs to be an external redirect for JS to handle the response), etc.

Comment: Who is upvoting this?!

Comment: The ^/* matches and $1 is not always empty, I tested it before I posted it